# xsl:key element in XSLT 2.0 Syntax question

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

The way I am using the `xsl:key` element and `key()` function do not seem to work. Is there a problem with my syntax?

Looked up the element and function on W3Schools but it looks to me as though my syntax matches theirs.
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/func_key.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_key.asp

My xml sample

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customerdatabase>
    <customer id="1" Shortname="Shortname1"/>
    <customer id="2" Shortname="Shortname2"/>
    <customer id="48412" Shortname="Shortname48412"/>
</customerdatabase>
```

My XSLT sample

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:dn="myPersonalNamespace">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="contents" match="/customerdatabase/customer" use="@id"/>

    <xsl:template name="MasterTemplate" match="customerdatabase">

        <xsl:result-document href="keyTest.xmi">
            <dn:Output xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:dn="myPersonalNamespace">
                <dn:Test1>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('contents', 48412)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Shortname"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </dn:Test1>
                <dn:Test2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('contents',1)/@Shortname"/>
                </dn:Test2>
                <dn:Test3>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('contents',48412)/@Shortname"/>
                </dn:Test3>
            </dn:Output>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The resulting keyTest.xmi file is created but the Testx elements are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the XSLT/XPath 2 and later type system the values you pass to the key functions in your calls like `key('contents', 48412)` are literals of type `xs:integer` while your key declares `use="@id"` which will result in string values (in general, the atomized value of the attribute which will be a string unless you use schema aware XSLT) being used to build the key index. So either change the declaration to `use="xs:integer(@id)"` and your `key` calls should work or keep the declaration but change the calls to use strings e.g. `key('contents', '48412')`.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-key saying

> If the use attribute is present, its value is an expression specifying
>   the values of the key. The expression will be evaluated with the node
>   that matches the pattern as the context node. The result of evaluating
>   the expression is atomized.

and https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-key

> The $key-value argument to the key function is considered as a
>   sequence. The set of requested key values is formed by atomizing the
>   supplied value of the argument, using the standard function conversion
>   rules. Each of the resulting atomic values is considered as a
>   requested key value. The result of the function is a sequence of
>   nodes, in document order and with duplicates removed, comprising those
>   nodes in the selected subtree (see below) that are matched by an
>   xsl:key declaration whose name is the same as the supplied key name,
>   where the result of evaluating the key specifier contains a value that
>   is equal to one of these requested key values, under the rules
>   appropriate to the XPath eq operator for the two values in question

In XSLT 1 this is a bit different, key values are always string values and the `key` function converts arguments to strings, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#key saying:

> the value of the key (a string)

and https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#function-key

> When the second argument to the key function is of type node-set, then
>   the result is the union of the result of applying the key function to
>   the string value of each of the nodes in the argument node-set. When
>   the second argument to key is of any other type, the argument is
>   converted to a string as if by a call to the string function; it
>   returns a node-set containing the nodes in the same document as the
>   context node that have a value for the named key equal to this string